# Not able to identify html part storing the data on a webpage

Tags: python, html

I am trying to scrape data from this webpage `http://www.verizonwireless.com/wcms/consumer/shop/share-everything.html` using below mentioned code:

```
# -*- coding: cp1252 -*-
import csv
import urllib2
import sys
import urllib
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from itertools import islice


url = 'http://www.verizonwireless.com/wcms/consumer/shop/share-everything.html'
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1;Trident/5.0)'
req = urllib2.Request(url,headers={ 'User-Agent' : user_agent })
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
page = response.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)

tabcontent = soup.find('div', {"id": "uttsdPlanOptions", "class": "priceCol2"})
content = tabcontent.findAll('tr')
print content
```

After printing the content I realised I am not getting the data values in GB mentioned on website, when I tried inspecting element of the "GB" part I found this html structure `<p class="ptData">Shareable Data</p>` There was no mention of GB in this part also there was no image linked which could have explained the missing value of GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The value you are looking doesn't exist as text. It is an image obtained from URL `/content/dam/vzw/lobs/consumer/shop/share-everything/data-sprite.png` and cropped to size using CSS code:

```
.ptData{min-width:74px;background:transparent url(/content/dam/vzw/lobs/consumer/shop/share-everything/data-sprite.png) no-repeat;padding-top:52px;display:block;}
.data300mb .ptData{background-position:center top;}
.data1 .ptData{background-position:center -72px;}
.data2 .ptData{background-position:center -144px;}
.data4 .ptData{background-position:center -216px;}
.data6 .ptData{background-position:center -288px;}
.data8 .ptData{background-position:center -360px;}
.data10 .ptData{background-position:center -432px;}
.data12 .ptData{background-position:center -504px;}
.data14 .ptData{background-position:center -576px;}
.data16 .ptData{background-position:center -648px;}
.data18 .ptData{background-position:center -720px;}
.data20 .ptData{background-position:center -792px;}
.data30 .ptData{background-position:center -864px;}
.data40 .ptData{background-position:center -936px;}
.data50 .ptData{background-position:center -1008px;}
```

The table you are trying to obtain the values from has records this like:

```
<td class="data2">
    <p>Unlimited Talk &amp; Text with</p>
    <p class="ptData">Shareable Data</p>
</td>
```

The `class` attribute of the `<p>` tag gets the image based on the `class` attribute of the preceding `<td>` (inherited). So can derive the value you want from the `class` attribute value in the `<td>` tag.